# How can I view profiling information visually in Julia?

Tags: julia

I find the plain text profile information very hard to read in Julia.

First I tried to use [ProfileView.jl](https://github.com/timholy/ProfileView.jl), but I had trouble installing it.

Is there another method people commonly use to view this information visually?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202755/discussion-on-question-by-marouane1994-how-can-i-view-profiling-information-visu).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this is still really just a tool request even after the edit.

Answer (score 9):

ProfileView relies on Gtk, which can be a pain to setup. Luckily, there are at least three good alternatives:

### PProf.jl (browser)

https://github.com/vchuravy/PProf.jl

Lots of different options to look at the profile, needs you to install graphviz manually. Might become my favorite, but haven't used it as much yet, since I just started using it recently.

### StatProfilerHTML (browser)

https://github.com/tkluck/StatProfilerHTML.jl

Pretty simple flamegraph visualizer

### Juno's inbuild profiler (Atom)

My goto solution. Just use `@profiler` in Atom, and you'll get the flamegraph in the plot-pane... Super handy: it jumps right to the file + line of the function, when you click into the flamegraph... 
Disadvantage: the flamegraph is pretty basic, and zooming seems to be broken last time I tried.